# HTTP 1.1 Gateway Timeout 504

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have developed an MERN Application so we have ReactJS as frontend and backend as NodeJS. The Application is working on Heroku server.

But now i am scaling things up and I have moved to AWS. I have deployed the frontend in S3 and using it as Static Web Hosting. I have deployed backend in EC2 instance and it is running on NGINX.

We have few resources required such as Camera to be accessed from the browser so I have added SSL certificates on both ends. In EC2 I have used loadbalancer to add SSL certificate.

Now the issue is when ever i make an API call from frontend to backend i am getting GATEWAY TIMEOUT 504 exception.

Frontend : https://portal.visitplan.in

Backend: https://api.visitplan.in

Can you help us out in resolving this? or is this the right way to deploy the application? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all, your certificate is invalid, you might wanna check on that.

I might know what is happen even thought you are not providing any code.

You might have deployed the frontend and the backend but you might have forgotten to change the request, however, the only request I can make from the portal is the login and this is the console response:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.visitplan.in/account/login' from origin 'https://portal.visitplan.in' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

You need to add the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`as stated here. [CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin)

One of those reasons might be the problem.

Comment: I have CORS Policy issue but now i am facing gate way timeout exception. You can check above url and suggest us how to resolve